# Onclick populate unique text into a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a table to get data from the database, I have a link for each row that gets generated dynamically in my table, if you click on that link a bootstrap modal will appear e.g.

```
        $(document).on("click", ".edit", function (e) {
        $('.showthis').modal('show');
    });

<div class="modal fade showthis">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my table I am getting an individual ID for each row e.g:

```
     row += '<td>' + data[mod].someText+ '<id-flip="' + data[mod].ID + '"></td>';
     row += '<td><a href="#" class="edit" id= "' + data[mod].ID + '"></td>';
```

**Question is:** that how would I get the information `data[mod].someText` and place that into `id="textArea"` Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
document.getElementById('textArea').innerHTML = data[mod].someText;
```

And with jQuery:

```
$('#textArea').html(data[mod].someText);
```